# Add a custom namespace and use it in openxml excel via c# openxml sdk

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there an example to add a custom namespace

e.g.

```
xmlns:bluh = "http://www.bluhbluh.com"
```

at `Workbook/WorkbookPart/SpreadSheetDocument` level

using a C# OpenXml SDK?

Comment: @Nostradamus thank you for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** add a custom namespace to the spreadsheet, word document, etc... OOXML format doesn't allow it.

see the blog post by Gray Knowlton http://blogs.technet.com/b/gray_knowlton/archive/2009/12/23/what-is-custom-xml-and-the-impact-of-the-i4i-judgment-on-word.aspx

archive link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20091226044101/http://blogs.technet.com/gray_knowlton/archive/2009/12/23/what-is-custom-xml-and-the-impact-of-the-i4i-judgment-on-word.aspx